# How to remove a subdocument matching a condition from an array of subdocuments in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, subdocument

I have a MongoDB database containing documents in the following format:

```
  {
  "name": "",
  "surname": "",
  "ssn": "",
  "tests": [
    {
      "date": "",
      "attending": [
        {
          "id": "",
          "role": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

A document contains, for each person, a list of tests with their relative information. I woud like to remove from each document only the subdocuments (belonging to the *tests* array) which were performed after a certain date (2019-02-22) and by a certain nurse (id = 0187).

Since all the dates are saved in *string* format, for date comparison I used the `$dateFromString` operator in the following way:

```
db.Vaccinations.aggregate([
"$match": {
  "$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
      "$gte": [
        { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$tests.date"}},
        ISODate("2019-02-22T00:00:00Z")
      ]},
      {
        "tests.attending.id" : "0187"
      }
    ]
    }
  }
])
```

However I wasn't able to use the `$pull` operator to remove the coerresponding subdocuments. Is it possible to do so or is `$pull` the wrong operator?

Comment: The [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#examples) is used with _update_ operations - to remove a matching array element.

Comment: @prasad_ so is it possible to compare dates without the aggregation pipeline?

Comment: Yes. You can use the `$expr` within an _update_ operations query filter.

Comment: can you fix the data to be valid JSON? that array is opened but doesn't close and its not clear how are your data, that id of nurse. [you can use something like this](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print) to check the syntax

Comment: @Takis_ now it should be fixed. Regarding the data, all fields are just strings (for the nurse id it is hust a string with four digits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- from tests keep only those
- or

  - `date < "2019-02-22"`
  - `nurse != "0187"`
    This way a test to pass it must be in before date or done from another nurse.
- `nurse != "0187"` is checked using a path "$test.attending.id" to get all the ids of that test(an array), and test that the intersection with `["0187"]` is empty => that nurse didn't do the test.

*you can use updateOne or updateMany depending on your needs

*i didn't use `$dateFromString` if dates have the same format like
`YYYY-MM-DD` comparison will work, but in general save dates in the database, it makes things easier and faster.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70213405)

```js
update(
{},
[{"$set": 
   {"tests": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$tests",
        "cond": 
         {"$or": 
           [{"$lt": ["$$test.date", "2019-02-22"]},
            {"$eq": 
              [{"$setIntersection": [["0187"], "$$test.attending.id"]}, []]}]},
        "as": "test"}}}}])
```

Comment: I think that with this solution, if one of the tests matches the condition, all the tests associated to that person are deleted but my initention was to delete just the tests taken after that date by that nurse

Comment: test it with the sample data, and send a link that doesn't work to fix it, the above code keeps the test if date < 2019.... or that nurse was not part of the attending array , either share a link or send data that doesn't work and describe how it should be if possible

Comment: maybe you want to keep a test if that nurse was in the attending array but wasnt alone? 
give an example if possible

Comment: no i wanted to delete just the tests made by that nurse after the date, both conditions have to be true together so if for instance that nurse made a test but before the specified date then i should keep that test

Comment: ok that code does that, you tested it and it didn't work? send an example that didn't work, to be fixed

Comment: i tried your solution on this dataset: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1841z87vM8dq3EDc78a4Z4Pw8Sb4BBL0O/view?usp=sharing) however if you look for example at the person with ssn = "451-99-7700" all his test are deleted after running the query even tough only the first one should be

Comment: you are right i mistyped before `"$test.attending.id"` instead of  `"$$test.attending.id"`, i think now its ok, and does what you need.